# Internet Exploer 8 - Internet Access Issue

Tags: proxy, internet-explorer-8

I am using IE8 since last 6 months and its working fine. I am using it by providing proxy server address. 
Suddenly it started not working today. Strange thing is that it fails to communicate with proxy server. It still

work if I use modem as internet connection, its just has problem with proxy server communicationl. Even my Firefox

is working fine. And all installed application like Yahoo Messanger and skype working fine.

I also uninstalled and reinstalled, but no luck.

Any work around? Have anybody faced this issue?

Thanks 
Paresh

Comment: Use a decent browser, like Chrome, Safari, Firefox or Opera. Also http://superuser.com/

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an actual proxy server?  Or are you using a home-grade router/access point?  If you just have a router, try turning off the Proxy setting in IE8.  IE* should work with the default gateway setting that your network gets from DHCP.  Your Default Gateway setting is good or Yahoo Messenger, and Skype would not work...